# error while executing play bat in windows xp

Tags: playframework

I installed play framework in my windows xp with no issues. However, 
I got the following error when I tried to run play command in play application "myFirstApp" directory. It is supposed to take me to play console (as per the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/PlayConsole) ) with no issues.
Am I doing some thing wrong ?

```
C:\Apps\myFirstApp>play
C:\Apps\play-2.0.3\play-2.0.3\
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Apps\myFirstApp\project
[error] play#play_2.9.1;2.0.3!play_2.9.1.jar origin location must be absolute: /Users/phausel/i/play-2.0.3/hh/../framewo
[error] {file:/C:/Apps/myFirstApp/project/}default-817509/*:update: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: play#play_2.9.1;
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem using Play 2.0.3, after creating a new project and running the "play" command.

If I use Play 2.0.2 instead, and create a new project again, I can run the "play" command without any issue.

Therefore I reckon either:

- something has not been properly configured in the 2.0.3 package, or
- something incorrect has been accidentally packaged in 2.0.3.

It would be good to have an official answer though.

M.

---

EDIT:

- I noticed a huge difference in size between 2.0.2 and 2.0.3: 95MB for the first one, 128 MB for the second one, which is surprising given the versioning would make think it is a minor upgrade. It suggests they may indeed have done something wrong with the packaging.
- Looking for the string "origin location must be absolute: /Users/phausel" in Play 2.0.3, I also found it was all over the place, in play-2.0.3\repository\cache, which is not there after extraction in 2.0.2, but is indeed there after extraction in 2.0.3.
- I have deleted everything under play-2.0.3\repository, and Play is now downloading everything again. I will update with the outcome when finished.

---

WORKAROUND:

1. Download 2.0.3
2. Extract it
3. Delete repository\cache
4. Use Play as usual. Note that first call to "play" will take a while as it will download all dependencies.

I have also sent an email on the [Play Framework Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/7MAaAoDSJmY) to make them aware of this issue.
Waiting for a reply.

---

SOLUTION: The package has now been fixed by the Play Framework team.
Either use the link below or the "official" one on the Play Framework website for 2.0.3.

Comment: Could you try the solution I added and let us know the outcome?

Comment: Carre , Thanks for the solution. I did not get a chance to try it. However , the issue was  solved with the play2.0.3 patch  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2721142/updated/play-2.0.3.zip.

Answer (score 2):

My problem turns out to be a corrupted ivy cache. After deleting ~/.ivy2, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, please try https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2721142/updated/play-2.0.3.zip